# Upload a file using boto

Tags: python, boto

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3('',  '')

mybucket = conn.get_bucket('data_report_321')
```

I can download the file from a bucket using the following code.

```
for b in mybucket:
     print b.name
     b.get_contents_to_filename('0000_part_00', headers=None, cb=None, num_cb=10, torrent=False, version_id=None, res_download_handler=None, response_headers=None)
```

But I am **not able to upload** a file. I get an error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell'

send_file nor set_contents functions are working as expected.

```
for b in mybucket:
     b.send_file('mytest.txt', headers=None, cb=None, num_cb=10, query_args=None, chunked_transfer=False, size=None)
     b.set_contents_from_file('mytest.txt', headers=None, replace=True, cb=None, num_cb=10, policy=None, md5=None, reduced_redundancy=False, query_args=None, encrypt_key=False, size=None, rewind=False)
```

How do I upload a file from current directory of local server to S3 bucket using boto?

---

Update:
I need to declare the key (filename) of the uploaded file first before calling the set_contents_from_filename function.

```
k = boto.s3.key.Key(mybucket)
k.key = 'uploaded_file.txt'
k.set_contents_from_filename("myteswt.txt")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both [send_file](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.send_file) and [set_contents_from_file](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_file) take a `File` object for first argument. If you would like to pass a string you should see [set_contents_from_filename](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_filename).

Comment: I do not get any error with set_contents_from_filename but the file is not really uploaded to that bucket. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

You could use this utility script: https://github.com/TimelyToga/upload_s3

```
python upload_s3.py <filename> [key_to_upload_as]
```

That will upload any file to a s3 bucket that you specify.

Although, when you are uploading `set_contents_from_file` takes a python `File` object.