# python boto set_contents_from_filename gives FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-s3, anaconda, boto3

I'm trying to upload a local file via Boto set_contents_from_filename(). I followed the tutorial instructions [here](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-data) but no luck. I also tried variations mentioned in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952684/upload-a-file-using-boto) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317243/boto-uploading-file-to-a-specific-location-on-amazon-s3) but I get the same error.

Any attempt calling set_contents_from_filename gives "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

My python script is in the same subdir as the file I want to upload: AWS_Upload.txt. My working directory is also set correctly. I can successfully call set_contents_from_**string**() so I know everything else works (my keys, my bucket, etc.)

Also, the FILE_PATH constants below are left over from trying the os.path.join to create a proper full path, but I received the same error.

Lastly, the file really does exist. I copy and paste c:\Apps\Docs\Python\MyPy\AWS_Upload.txt into Windows File Explorer and the file appears in Notepad.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.sqs

ACCESS_KEY='mykey'
SECRET_ACCES_KEY='mysecret'
BUCKET = 'pybucket234'

FILE_PATH = 'c:\\Apps\\Docs\\Python\\MyPy\\'
FILE_UPLOAD = 'AWS_Upload.txt'

conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, 
                       aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCES_KEY)

# Save some data
bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET) 
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'myfilekey'
k.set_contents_from_filename('AWS_Upload.txt')
# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AWS_Upload.txt'

# Tried this as well but get the same error
k.set_contents_from_filename('c:\Apps\Docs\Python\MyPy\AWS_Upload.txt')

# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Apps\\Docs\\Python\\MyPy\\AWS_Upload.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly changed the imports and used boto.connect_s3() instead. The code above worked for me several times today across different buckets. The 'FileNotFoundErrors' above no longer appear.